# (Java) I'm trying to create a Jagged 2D Array with elements input by the User. Is this possible?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm creating a mock gradebook program for a class assignment, and I'm trying to make my arrays streamlined, with no null values.

**The Arrays:**

- Names: A One-Dimensional array that holds student names.
- DummyNames: A One-Dimensional array that holds a maximum of 20 student names, then transfers them to Names.
- Grades: A Two-Dimensional array that holds the student grades.
- DummyGrades: A Two-Dimensional array that holds a maximum of 100 student grades, then transfers them to Grades.

My issue is transferring DummyGrades to Grades with no blank elements. Since the user instantiates the values, I can't go in and manually enter the values. Here's my main class:

```
    //get grades for each person with DummyGrades
    int [][] DummyGrades = new int [100][counter];

    //cycle through and enter grades
    System.out.println("Enter a maximum of 100 grades per person. Type \"-1\" to finish. ");
    for(int col = 0; col < DummyGrades[0].length; col ++)
    {
        for(int row = 0; row < DummyGrades.length; row ++)
        {
            System.out.print("Entering Grade " + (row + 1) + " for " + Names[col] + ": ");
            intput = scan.nextInt();
            if(intput == -1)
            {
                row = DummyGrades.length;
            }
            else
            {
                DummyGrades[row][col] = intput;
                intCounter ++;
            }
        }
        //cycle through and enter each grade into the real grades

        //????
    }
```

Disclaimer: There may be errors in the above code, I haven't compiled it yet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about nulls in your arrays.  The point of an array is to make a place to record each value.  If there is no value for that place, then use null to say that.

You are using arrays, which have a fixed size, which is defined by the size of the grid you want to produce.  You could use lists to save space, but these seems to be no utility in that.  If the spot of the grid is blank, use a null.

Comment: Thanks, but if I'm printing out the curve grades (sqrt[grade] * 10) of a student, will the null elements prove an issue for me?

Comment: Yes, you need to test for null, and not do the wrong thing.  Null is not a zero.  For average, you add the sum the values, but divide by the number of *non-null* values.   The nulls should act in math exactly as if they didn't exist.

Comment: Ok, so would any math equation with null in it just print out null?